# Getting IUIItem[] for children of CustomUIItem in TestStack.White

Tags: c#, wpf, white-framework

A WPF Application is using an Application Framework and I can edit neither of them.

I can visit every element in the GUI doing something along these lines:

```
IUIItem[] items = window.GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.All);
foreach (var item in items)
{
    visit((dynamic)item);
}
```

I have no Issue with normal controls but I hit a wall with `CustomUIItem`.

I would like to visit all the Children of it but I fail to make a new array `IUIItem[]` from them.

Here is what I have now:

```
    void visit(CustomUIItem item)
    {
        AutomationElementCollection children =
            item
            .AutomationElement
            .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);
        UIItemCollection temp = new UIItemCollection(children.Cast<AutomationElement>());
        foreach(var t in temp)
        {
            visit((dynamic)t);
        }
    }
```

Somethimes this throws and most of the time collection remains empty.

The `CusomControl` has "normal" controls among its children.
I want those as regular `IUIItem`s.

Where can I find the documentation for this.
The only thing I found was [this](http://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AdvancedTopics/CustomUIItems/), and I can not do that since I am only visiting from outside and I do not know the controls content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i have really understood your problem.

```
    IUIItem[] items = window.GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.All);
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        visit(item);
    }
```

I have update your visit() method, it takes now a IUItem as argument to allow visiting of normal and custom controls.

```
    public void visit(IUIItem item)
    {
        if (item is CustomUIItem)
        {
            // Process custom controls
            CustomUIItem customControl = item as CustomUIItem;

            // Retrieve all the child controls
            IUIItem[] items = customControl.AsContainer().GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.All);

            // visit all the children
            foreach (var t in items)
            {
                visit(t);
            }
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            // Process normal controls
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: You did not make use of the (dynamic) keyword. But I think utilizing AsContainer is what I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, i have just supposed that the goal of the visit() method was only to browse the UIItems tree in a recursive way. Now i see that your real visit() method is probably more complex than the given code ;-).