# Is there a way to get all the elements inside a Custom Control type in TestStack.White

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation

I just created a desktop application in Visual Studio using WPF Framework, and my application contains a lot of custom control types. The purpose of this application  is to learn automation using TestStack.White.

Most of this I am able to automate except the custom control type. The actual issue is, I am not able to get the elements inside the custom control. While Googling, I found something like

```
CustomUIItem customControl = item as CustomUIItem;
IUIItem[] items = customControl.AsContainer().GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.All);
```

but for my C# code, `customControl.AsContainer()` is not working. I don't know if it is because of any version dependency. So if anyone knows a way to use `AsContainer()` with custom control types in TestStack.White, please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting IUIItem\[\] for children of CustomUIItem in TestStack.White](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881079/getting-iuiitem-for-children-of-customuiitem-in-teststack-white)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your Question correctly, you should be able to just do

```
CustomUIItem customControl = item as CustomUIItem;
IUIItem[] items = customControl.GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.All);
```

as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881079/getting-iuiitem-for-children-of-customuiitem-in-teststack-white) answered

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? What about it doesn't work?